# access lable control kept in layout of listview?

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding

I have one dropdownlist and one button and listview.  Button and dropdownlist is outside listview.
On 1st page load, all the item is displayed. Now user can see based on selection of dropdownlist.

I want to show selected text of dropdownlist in lable of layout control of listview.

I wrote below code but doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
protected void lvProduct_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlCategory.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string Category= dlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            (lvProduct.FindControl("lblCategory") as Label).Text = "Category: " + dlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            (lvProduct.FindControl("lblCategory") as Label).Text = "All category";
        }
    }
```

Comment: try it in ItemBound event instead of LayoutCreated

Comment: @vhinn terrible: Thanks. works perfectely in ItemDataBound.